# Mini Cooper S (R53) - ABS sensor and magnetic ring (?) replacement

Tags: abs, mini-cooper, wheel-speed-sensor

I have the three lights on my dash on my Mini Cooper (R53) which from research shows a problem related to the ABS sensor. Over the weekend we plugged it into a machine and sure enough it's the passenger side, front sensor at fault.

I had this about 2 years a go and we replaced the same sensor. The light didn't immediately go out but then for a good year it did (I've read it should be a short drive for the light to go off, in my case it was like 2 weeks!).

Anyway, the lights are back on and apparently it's the same sensor.

The mechanic who tested my car mentioned about a magnetic ring which could also be the problem (or ABS ring?). I'm not very good with cars but a quick Google looks like it's a pretty simple job to replace the ABS sensor but I can't find much about this magnetic ring.

Can any one point me in the direction as to what part they're referring to and where it is located, and how to replacement it if possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* sure about the MINI Cooper S, but on *most cars* you don't replace the magnetic (or reluctor) ring when replacing the sensor. You don't need to unless there's been some kind of accident or something where it physically gets damaged. The ring is usually just a reluctor wheel which activates the ABS sensor (most of the time it's a Hall effect sensor). It is usually pressed into place on the axle shaft or is located inside of the hub assembly (therefore not replaceable unless you replace the hub). Looking at both the axle shafts and hub assemblies, I don't see where it would be attached. I also don't find a separate part listed for the reluctor wheel. To me, it doesn't make sense to be replacing it to fix your issue.

As far as the wheel speed (or ABS) sensor, there's only one bolt which attaches it, then there are a few places where the wire looms through and attaches to body parts. It should be very easily replaced.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the part either, unless the entire hub needs to be replaced (but that's probably going too far?). The reason is as I mention before it was replaced and the same is faulty again. I shall replace it and see what happens this weekend and update. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Ricky replacing the wheel bearing to repair a broken encoder ring is all too common don’t waste your money without doing some testing with a scope. If you can’t, take it to a professional that you can trust.